# composer.json file property name is required

Tags: composer-php

I am using composer for the first time so if I shouldn't be posting here I am very sorry.

I am following a youtube tutorial on the paypal api I have installed composer and created the json file the same as the example. composer.json is saved in the root folder for the website.  the structure is below.  composer diagnose composer.json: fail and property name is required.

```
{
"require": {
    "paypal/rest-api-php": "1.5.1"
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

looks like your composer had much fresher version, check `composer --version` !

need to update **composer.json** with:

```
{
"name": "some/name",
"description": "Some description will be useful too!",

"require": {
    "paypal/rest-api-php": "1.5.1"
}
}
```

or install  some old version, by exec 3lines

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer  --version=1.0.1
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to start a project using Composer:

```
composer init
```

This will ask you some questions, some of them with sensible defaults that you can simply accept - others (like the name of your project) cannot be guessed.

The best way to install a package after that

```
composer require package/name
```

Optionally for development packages:

```
composer require --dev package/name
```

The `composer` command used here assumes you have downloaded "composer.phar" and renamed or symlinked it in a way that it can be called just by typing `composer`. Otherwise, replace that command with the one that works for you, like `php composer.phar` or `composer.phar`.